# How to combine similar JavaScript methods to one

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have an ASP.NET code-behind page linking several checkboxes to JavaScript methods.  I want to make only one JavaScript method to handle them all since they are the same logic, how would I do this?

Code behind page load:

```
checkBoxShowPrices.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return checkBoxShowPrices_click(event);");

checkBoxShowInventory.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return checkBoxShowInventory_click(event);");
```

ASPX page JavaScript; obviously they all do the same thing for their assigned checkbox, but I'm thinking this can be reduced to one method:

```
function checkBoxShowPrices_click(e) {
    if (_hasChanged) {
        confirm(
            'All changes will be lost. Do you wish to continue?',    
            function(arg) {
                if (arg.toUpperCase() == 'YES') {
                    var checkBox = document.getElementById('<%=checkBoxShowPrices.UniqueID%
>');
                    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
                    eval("<%=base.GetPostBackEventReference(checkBoxShowPrices)%>");
                    _hasChanged = false;
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            eval("<%=base.GetPostBackEventReference(checkBoxShowPrices)%>");
    }
}
    
function checkBoxShowInventory_click(e) {
    if (_hasChanged) {
        confirm(
            'All changes will be lost. Do you wish to continue?', 
            function(arg) {
                if (arg.toUpperCase() == 'YES') {
                    var checkBox = document.getElementById('<%
=checkBoxShowInventory.UniqueID%>');
                    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
                    eval("<%=base.GetPostBackEventReference(checkBoxShowInventory)%>");
                    _hasChanged = false;
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            eval("<%=base.GetPostBackEventReference(checkBoxShowInventory)%>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you edit the code to be less newliney?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the event the checkbox that is raising it:

```
checkBoxShoPrices.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return checkBox_click(this, event);");
```

Afterwards in the function you declare it like this:

```
function checkBoxShowPrices_click(checkbox, e){ ...}
```

and you have in checkbox the instance you need

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a function that returns a function:

```
function genF(x, y) {
    return function(z) { return x+y*z; };
};

var f1 = genF(1,2);
var f2 = genF(2,3);

f1(5);
f2(5);
```

That might help in your case, I think. (Your code-paste is hard to read..)